# Why are code snippets uncopyable when using "mkdocs build"?

Tags: mkdocs, mkdocs-material

Why code snippets can be copied when running "mkdocs serve" with the mkdocs-material theme, but not when using "mkdocs build"?

Using `mkdocs serve` is resulting in:

[image: abcd]

Using `mkdocs build` there is no "copied" button:

[image]

How can I enable copying of code snippets in the static files generated by `mkdocs build`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer: [mkdocs-material docs](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/reference/code-blocks/?h=content+code+copy#code-copy-button)

I found out that I wrote one less feature parameter in the latest version, as follow:

```yaml
theme:
  name: material
  features:
    - announce.dismiss
    - content.action.edit
    - content.action.view
    - content.code.annotate
    - content.code.copy
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really configured the ***mkdocs-material*** theme, the Copy icon will also appear in the generated static HTML pages.

Perform the following steps as a simple test case e.g. using PowerShell:

1. Create new project `mkdocs new test`
2. Goto to test directory `cd test`
3. Open `mkdocs.yml` using your favorite text editor.
4. Add the theme like shown below

```yaml
site_name: My Docs
# ============================================
# APPEARANCE
# ============================================
theme:
  name: material
```

5. Run `mkdocs build`

When you open `site/index.html` this is resulting in:

[image]

Tested on Windows 10 22H2, mkdocs 1.4.2, mkdocs-material 8.5.6