# Why are code snippets uncopyable when using "mkdocs build"? with mk-docs Material

Tags: mkdocs, mkdocs-material

[I found a post with the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76162517/why-are-code-snippets-uncopyable-when-using-mkdocs-build/76457505#76457505), but the solution is not working for my issue.

I have the same issue than the original post.

In "serve" I have the copy Button, but in "build" i don"'t have it. (it was working in v8.x)

The version:

```
mkdocs==1.4.3
mkdocs-cinder==1.2.0
mkdocs-cluster==0.0.9
mkdocs-gitbook==0.0.1
mkdocs-material==9.1.15
mkdocs-material-extensions==1.1.1
mkdocs-pdf-export-plugin==0.5.10
```

the yaml:

```yaml
    site_name: Doc 4 Doc, la doc pour faire de la doc, oui oui
    site_author: Jungledede
    site_url: ""
    use_directory_urls: false
    theme:
        name: material
        locale: en
        logo: assets/images/COGIP-logo-rvb.png 
        favicon: assets/images/redface.png
        features:
            - content.code.copy
            - navigation.instant  
            - header.autohide 
            - navigation.sections
    
        palette:
            - media: "(prefers-color-scheme: light)" 
              scheme: default
              primary: amber
              accent: amber
              toggle:
                icon: material/weather-sunny
                name: Switch to dark mode
            - media: "(prefers-color-scheme: dark)" 
              scheme: slate
              primary: amber
              accent: amber
              toggle:
               icon: material/weather-night
               name: Switch to light mode 
        extra:
            copyright: Copyright &copy; 2022 - 2023 COGIP
        font: false
    
    markdown_extensions:
        - admonition
        - pymdownx.arithmatex:
            generic: true
        - pymdownx.betterem:
            smart_enable: all
        - pymdownx.caret
        - pymdownx.details
        - pymdownx.emoji:
            emoji_index: !!python/name:materialx.emoji.twemoji 
            emoji_generator: !!python/name:materialx.emoji.to_svg
        - pymdownx.highlight:
            auto_title: true
            use_pygments: true
            pygments_lang_class: true
            linenums: true
            linenums_style: pymdownx-inline
        - pymdownx.inlinehilite
        - pymdownx.keys
        - pymdownx.mark
        - pymdownx.smartsymbols
        - pymdownx.superfences
            #custom_fences:
                #- name: mermaid
                #  class: mermaid
                #  format: !!python/name:pymdownx.superfences.fence_div_format
        - pymdownx.smartsymbols
        - pymdownx.snippets
        - pymdownx.tabbed:
            alternate_style: true
        - pymdownx.tasklist:
            custom_checkbox: true
        - pymdownx.tilde
        - smarty 
        - tables 
        - toc:
    #       toc_depth : "1-1"
            permalink: true
            
    plugins:
        - pdf-export:
            verbose: true
            media_type: print
            combined: false
            enabled_if_env: ENABLE_PDF_EXPORT 
        - offline
        - search     
    
    #extra_javascript:
      #- 'assets/javascripts/mermaid.min.js'
      #- 'assets/javascripts/mermaid.js'
      #- 'assets/javascripts/mathjax.js'
    extra_css:
      - 'assets/stylesheets/font.css'
      - 'assets/stylesheets/extra.css'
      #- 'assets/pdfexport/report.css'
      #- 'assets/stylesheets/pdf.css'
      - 'assets/stylesheets/_typeset.scss'
      
    nav:
      - Index : 'index.md'
      - How to install: 'install.md'
      - How to set-up: 
        - mkdocs.yml: 'mkdocs_yml.md'
        - theme: 'theme.md'
```

I don't see what i miss. I put the - content.code.copy as indicated, but no luck in build. When pdf export is desable, the same.

In 'serve', i have the copy button, but not in 'build'.